# WindowBuilder Custom Look and Feel Not Previewing

Tags: windowbuilder

Using Eclipse Neon which comes pre-packaged with WindowBuilder V 1.8.0.  The Add > New and browsing to the custom look and feel .jar file that contains the Look And Feel code works well.  But when this custom Look and Feel is previewed, the preview comes up blank for all gui elements such as button, checkboxes, labels , etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that WindowBuilder 1.8 does not support the newer SYNTH Look and Feel but only supports the older look and feel.  When we tried to preview our Synth look and feel, all gui elements were blank.  But when we loaded our older look and feel which was written way before the SYNTH look and feel, then all of the gui elements (radio buttons, buttons, checkboxes, etc) showed the older look and feel.